# post request Error parsing media type 'application/xml' with netbeans

Tags: xml, json, rest, netbeans, jersey

I have implemented some rest webservices with netbeans IDE , but when testing the post request I get some exceptions like the following :

```
 POST RequestFailed RequestFailed --> Status: (500) 
 Response: { ......
 javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type ', application/xml'
 Content may not have Container-Containee Relationship.
```

and the code associated to the post method is

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(Mobilereading entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}
```

Normally everything seems to be correct but I don't know where is the problem ? any solutions plz *

[image]

Answer (score 1):

modify our code as

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(JAXBElement<Mobilereading> entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}
```